# How put a texture on pixi.js polygon?

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

Can I fill a polygon with a texture in pixi.js?

I need to create a polygon with points and fill it with a texture. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can fill a polygon with a Texture, but you can you use the polygon as a mask for a Sprite, which would have the same effect. Something like this will work:

```
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0, true);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(620, 380);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

//create a texture
var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("/img/logo.png");
var tilingSprite = new PIXI.TilingSprite(texture, 620, 380);
stage.addChild(tilingSprite);

//create a polygon
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0);
graphics.moveTo(50,50);
graphics.lineTo(300,140);
graphics.lineTo(220, 320);
graphics.lineTo(80, 110);
graphics.lineTo(50,50);
graphics.endFill();
stage.addChild(graphics);

//mask the texture with the polygon
tilingSprite.mask = graphics;

update();
function update()
{    
    requestAnimFrame( update );
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7asnhk3b/